# How to Fix Empty text boxes issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am facing the issue that when I click Login button on my Login page after inserting credentials, text boxes are not showing any data and right after I click on the login button my page refreshes..

I have tried:

- deleting the page
- clearing cache
- old button with new button
- changed textboxes

```
<asp:TextBox ID="email1" CssClass="form-control"  required="true" 
placeholder="Enter your Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="password1" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="password" 
required="true" placeholder="Enter your Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click"      
CssClass="btn btn-cv1" Text="Login" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

code behind it

```
con = Connection.authorize();
string query = "select * from UsersTB where E_Mail = '" + this.email1.Text + "' and password = '" + this.password1.Text.ToString() + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) 
{
  if (email1.Text == reader[1].ToString() && password1.Text == reader[2].ToString())
  {
    Session["E_Mail"] = reader[0].ToString();
    Response.Redirect("UserDashborad.aspx");
    Session.RemoveAll();
  }
  else if (email1.Text == "admin@admin.com" && password1.Text == "admin")
  {
    Session["E_Mail"] = reader[1].ToString();
    Response.Redirect("../admin/AdminDashboard.aspx");
    Session.RemoveAll();
  }
}
```

when I click Login button It must go to next page.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Does it execute the Response.Redirect code?

Comment: Did you check any JavaScript error? Debug the code first.

Comment: Could it only be that there's a typo? `Response.Redirect("UserDashborad.aspx");`
You typed `UserDashborad`... Also, provide the error message that you get if you did use the debug feature. It would be helpful to know what is happening in your code.

Also your title is different from your question. Be more clear please.

Comment: do you check the session in the `page_load` event of `UserDashborad.aspx`? If yes, then your session is not available, because you wrote `Session.RemoveAll()` before redirection. Additionally I recommend you that don't check username and password with that way, because there is `sql injection` in your code. Your site/app will be hacked very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You might have disable viewstate.